# Worksheet function in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

So I'm trying to create a function in VBA to whenever I type in specific parameters to a function in excel that'll give me the outcome of those parameters.

For example, I have a list of names in one column; John, Jane, and Joey.... and then in another column I've got numbers that coincide with those names... The objective here is for the user to type in a function in any given cell with the name and have the spreadsheet output the number that goes with that name.

This is what I've got but I've hit a dead end because I've got no clue what to do.

```
Function NumberOfHits(Name As String)
Dim Vegetable As String 
NumberOfHits = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Name, Sheets("Hits From Player").Range("B38:D74"), 3)  
End Function
```

Answer (score 6):

This works fine for me both on and off the sheet called `Hits From Player` once

1. I made the function volatile (so that it updates). You can also use `RAND()` in combination with this formula for the same impact.
2. Did you remember to enclose *name* in `" "`

   `=NumberOfHits("mary")`

Recut function:

```
Function NumberOfHits(Name As String)
    Application.Volatile
    NumberOfHits = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Name, _
    Sheets("Hits From Player").Range("B38:D74"), 3)
End Function
```

*Updated:to handle no exact match try*

```
Function NumberOfHits(strName As String) As Variant
Dim StrOut

Application.Volatile

On Error Resume Next
StrOut = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(strName, _
Sheets("Hits From Player").Range("B38:D74"), 3, False)
On Error GoTo 0

If IsEmpty(StrOut) Then
    NumberOfHits = CVErr(xlErrNA)
Else
    NumberOfHits = StrOut
End If
End Function
```

Comment: + 1 Works for me too :)

Comment: +1 though I would output an error value such as #N/A when no match found, to be consistent with Excel style :-)

Comment: So it did the same thing for me as it did before, idk if my issue goes hand in hand with the fact that I've got other hard data(not formulas) on my sheet but it keeps returning "#N/A"

Comment: Can you pls post a sample file

Comment: @brettdj to be truly consistent you should return CVErr(xlErrNA)

Comment: @CoolBlue it is a string function output, I don't see adding a conversion function adding value

Comment: @brettdj You are correct, unless you change the return type to Variant. If you do that then this function will behave exactly like any other excel lookup function as suggested by Jean-François Corbett.  Since the result is loaded into a cell, there is no performance overhead to return a Variant. Just to check, I tested returning String vs returning Variant for 1,000 cells and got the same time: 0.4 seconds.  If you return "#N/A", as a literal string, then excel will not process that as an error in dependencies and wrappers. That's how I think it adds value.

Comment: @CoolBlue Updated as you suggested. :)

Comment: @brettdj smooth... +1 :)